# match cases based on range with alphabets

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<para>39B</para>
<para>76</para>
```

Here I'm able to match the exact number, but the problem came up when there is a range mentioned like below.

```
if the range 39A-39P
  print case1
if the range 72-85
  print case2
```

The code i tried

```
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w]+)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:variable name="regex1">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(regex-group(1), '^39[A-P]$')">
              <xsl:text>CAse 1</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>Case 2</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select = "$regex1"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

please let me know how can i solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain where you have those ranges, in the input XML, in your XSLT code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use regular expressions so for the alphanumeric case you can use

```
<xsl:template match="para[matches(., '^39[A-P]$')]">case1</xsl:template>
```

and a simple number comparison for the second case

```
<xsl:template match="para[. ge 72 and . le 85]">case2</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi martin, is there a way where i can use this with `contains` like `contains(text(), '^39[A-P]$')` in text template?

Comment: The function for regular expression matching is called `matches`, not `contains` which only does substring containment test. So you have to use `matches` if you want to use regular expressions. As for using it on text nodes, of course you can do that if needed but be aware that my suggestion intentionally anchored the pattern with `^` and `$` to make sure the content is exactly like the pattern and not simply contained in the element. If there can be other characters before or after the pattern you want to ignore  then use `para[matches(., '39[A-P]')]`.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I've tried based on your suggestion, but this is not working, can you please help me in fixing it. I'm asking for `contains` because i want to use it in a `choose`, there are multiple such instances ~28, and i just need to get the content using `text()` template match

Comment: If you want to use regular expression matching you need to use the `matches` function and not the `contains` function. It doesn't matter if it is XSLT `xsl:template match="..."` or `xsl:when test="..."`. As for "this is not working", well, the sample input has e.g. `<para>39B</para>`, the code you have now added does `regex="([\w]+)\.([\w]+)"` which would never match as there is no dot `.` in the `para` element.

Comment: Nice XSLT expressions, plus one.